# If a linear operator $(\mathcal D(A),A)$ is bounded below and closed, then $A\mathcal D(A)$ is closed

Tags: functional-analysis, proof-verification, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces

Let

- $H$ be a $\mathbb R$-Hilbert space
- $\mathcal D(A)$ be a subspace of $H$
- $A:\mathcal D(A)\to H$ be linear

Assume

1. $\exists k>0$ with $$\left\|Ax\right\|_H\ge k\left\|x\right\|_H\;\;\;\text{for all }x\in(\ker A)^\perp\cap\mathcal D(A)\tag1$$
2. If $(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}\subseteq\mathcal D(A)$ with $$\left\|x-x_n\right\|_H\xrightarrow{n\to\infty}0\tag2$$ for some $x\in H$ and $$\left\|f-Ax_n\right\|_H\xrightarrow{n\to\infty}0\tag3$$ for some $f\in H$, then $x\in\mathcal D(A)$ with $$Ax=f\tag4$$

> I want to show that $A\mathcal D(A)$ is a closed subspace of $H$.

Let $(f_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}\subseteq A\mathcal D(A)$ with $$\left\|f-f_n\right\|_H\xrightarrow{n\to\infty}\tag5$$ for some $f\in H$. By definition, $$f_n=Ax_n\;\;\;\text{for all }n\in\mathbb N\tag6$$ for some $(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}\subseteq\mathcal D(A)$. Now, maybe my logic is a little bit too complicated: Assume $f\ne0$. Then, $$\left\|f_n\right\|_H\xrightarrow{n\to\infty}\left\|f\right\|_H>0\tag7$$ and hence $$\left\|f_n\right\|_H>0\;\;\;\text{for all }n\ge N\tag8$$ for some $N\in\mathbb N$. Thus, $$x_n\in(\ker A)^\perp\cap\mathcal D(A)\;\;\;\text{for all }n\ge N\tag9$$ and hence $$\left\|x_m-x_n\right\|_H\le\frac1k\left\|A(x_m-x_n)\right\|_H\xrightarrow{m,\:n\to\infty}0\tag{10}$$ by $(1.)$. Since $H$ is complete, there is some $x\in H$ with $$\left\|x-x_n\right\|_H\xrightarrow{n\to\infty}0\tag{11}$$ and hence $x\in\mathcal D(A)$ with $Ax=f$ by (2.), i.e. $f\in A\mathcal D(A)$.

> Did I made any mistake? And what do we need to do, if $f=0$?

Comment: No, I think your solution is fine. The point was to make use of completeness and condition 1,2. If $f=0$, of course then $f\in A\mathcal{D}(A)$ as $\mathcal{D}(A)$ is a linear subspace